# If $\sigma \in A_n$ has a split conjugacy class, then $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ is not conjugate to $\sigma$ for odd $\tau$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $\sigma \in A_n$ such that the disjoint cycle decomposition of $\sigma$ contains no even cycles or cycles of the same length. Although there is one conjugacy class of $\sigma$ in $S_n$, there are two conjugacy classes of $\sigma$ in $A_n$. We can choose any permutation in the original $S_n$ conjugacy class to represent one of the two $A_n$ classes. But how can we find another permutation to represent the other $A_n$ class?
[These](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/464610/711748) [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260365/711748) suggest the following to be true:

> Let $\sigma \in A_n$. If the conjugacy class of $\sigma$ splits in $A_n$, then $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ is not conjugate (in $A_n$) to $\sigma$ for all $\tau \in S_n \setminus A_n$.

What is a proof of this fact?

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630459/show-that-all-elements-in-the-conjugacy-class-of-sigma-in-s-n-are-conjugate) we know that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} \neq \sigma$ for all odd $\tau$. But proving $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} $ is not conjugate (in $A_n$) to $\sigma$ seems to be a stronger claim.

Comment: Not really. Since $\rho\tau$ is odd for all $\rho \in A_n$, we have $\rho\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}\rho^{-1} \ne \sigma$.